# HTML5: Javascript to force offline cache rebuild?

Tags: javascript, html, offline-caching, html5-appcache

Following html5rocks' tutorial, I hoped that `window.applicationCache.update()` would help to force re-building the offline cache.
(http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/#toc-updating-cache)

The purpose is to allow the users to hit an "update cache" button. This, because even files (css, img, etc.) are modified, the computer/tablet doesn't even check them for udpates. The users are left with old content.

How can this be done in JS?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking "how the client should know that the files are modified", then the answer is simple - the cache manifest should contain some unique identifier which gets updated when those files are updated. I generate the manifest with PHP and use a combination of monotonous increasing revision number and MAX(filemtime) from all the cached files - when the manifest file is different from the one the client has, it will check all the manifest-listed files for updates.

`update()` triggers the update check and downloads the updates if there are any, but it doesn't actually replace old cached data with the new.

`swapCache()` will swap out the old cached version with a newly downloaded one.

However, at that point your old JS has already created all the plumbing your page depends on...

My html5 application calls `update()` periodically, and when the cache update is downloaded, it just displays a button to the user saying "Install Updates!", which simply reloads the page - that way the newly downloaded cache files are applied when the user chooses to, without breaking his workflow.